# While Read Stores Each User Entry without Spaces

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to ask the user to enter a few lines of text, it can by anything and I want to store it as a variable that I can call later on. I don't want to create multiple read commands, just one that can hold multiple paragraphs if needed.

I tried this:

```
echo "Enter your your paragraph:"
read -d '' -n 1 message

while read -d ''  -n 1 -t 2 c
do
        message+=$c
done
echo ""
echo "$message"
```

the output is always put into one line of text without spaces or anything. It would look like this when I run the code and enter a few lines of code:

```
Enter your broadcast message (When done, wait 2 seconds): 
This is supposed to be a sentence.
And so is this. 

Thisissupposedtobeasentence.Andsoisthis.
```

It should output the two sentences on sperate lines and with spaces included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` uses the characters in `$IFS` as word delimiters. Change your read statement to:

```
IFS= read -r -d ''  -n 1 -t 2 c
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `read` for this; requiring all typing to be done without any two-second pauses (and conversely, forcing a wait of two seconds to complete the input) is not very user-friendly. Instead, just read input directly from standard input, which for interactive use simply requires an EOF (<kbd>Control-d</kbd>) to finish the input.

```
c=$(</dev/stdin)
```